# Syntax error on token "int" , VariableDeclarationId expected after this token R.java error

Tags: android, android-xml, r.java-file

This is the error, which is generating again and again.
    I've cleaned my project.

```
 public static final class id {
        public static final int  =0x7f07005b;
        public static final int button1=0x7f070004;
        public static final int button2=0x7f070005;
        public static final int frameLayout1hardMatchup=0x7f070009;
```

There is no error in String.xml, here is my String.xml.

```
<string name="hello">Hello World, MemoryCardsActivity!</string>
<string name="app_name">Princess  Memory Cards</string>
<string name="text_name">Congrates</string>
 <string name="text_help">Turn over pairs of matching cards, tap to flip two cards, as the match happens, they get removed from the screen.Try to get all cards match in minimum moves and proceed to next level</string>
```

And also there is not any @+id kind of error.
What else could be the reason of this.
Any positive response would be really appreciated.. :(

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a variable name

```
public static final int  = 0x7f07005b;
```

instead

```
public static final int variableName = 0x7f07005b;
```

Comment: @blackbelt thanks, I don't like answers without a detailed explanation but... ;)

Comment: That's clear by it's name, but i've checked all my classes and xml files, i didn't find anything wrong there. Is there any way to detect where i would be missing it, if i am missng. :(

Comment: @VaishaliSharma you have to check if inside on of your xml you put an item like android:id=""

Comment: the "id" class is autogenerated in the R.java file, so: even fixing manually this file won't solve the problem!

Comment: i've used @+id everywhere.

Comment: But you need to make sure that you don't have an empty space after `@+id/`

Comment: Have you tried deleting the file and letting it regenerate itself?

Comment: yes, i've once delete R.java and when it re-generates again it again through the same error, i've cleaned my project also.

Comment: Check each of the XML files carefully. Look at each warning, or error.

Comment: @VaishaliSharma what was causing it?

Comment: in one of my layout, i missed to assign id of an imageView, it was like "@+id/ " there, i changed that to "@+id/imgView". it solved my problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I figured that's what it was but I was stumped after you said you checked them all. That can be easy to overlook with a lot of `View`s

Answer (score 1):

I produced a similar error by changing one of my layout XML files. I changed

```
android:id="@+id/image_frame"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/ "
```

The error I see with this change is

```
public static final int  =0x7f080010; 
// Syntax error on token "int", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
```

This seems to be what @codeMagic was describing.